# Define an access by key ( structure[key] ) for a custom structure struct?

Tags: associations

I have some "complicated" data that I want to encapsulate into a "struct":

For instance (imagine that data have several fields):

```
data=<|"A"->6,"B"->2|>
var=myType[data]
```

The advantage is that it is easy to filter your arguments:

```
doSomething[myType[d_]]:=d

(* usage: *)
doSomething[var]
```

Now I want to allow this:

```
var["B"] <- must return 2
```

But I do not know how to do that, any idea?

---

What I have done so far:

```
myType /: Key[k_][myType[d_]:=d[k]
```

This works for syntax like:

```
Key["B"][var]
```

but not for

```
var["B"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[myType]
myType /: myType[data_Association][s_String] := data[[s]]

var = myType[<|"A" -> 6, "B" -> 2|>];
var["B"]
```

> 2

Comment: Thanks again Henrik, my questions are too easy :-)

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: This definitely works, though it's good to notice that this sets a `SubValue` for `myType`, not an `UpValue`.